# Can FileVault protect a macOS partition from a Ubuntu partition?

Tags: macos, partition, filevault

I’m working on setting up Ubuntu dual-boot on my MacBook Pro, and I’m terrified of doing something that breaks one or more of the systems now on my computer (like an rm -rf that manages to hit both partitions somehow). I was thinking, would encrypting the macOS partition with FileVault serve to prevent Ubuntu from accidentally doing something to it, or is that not how any of this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are four types of Apple partitions that are commonly used:

- Apple_HFS (MacOS Extended Journaled)
- Apple_Boot (MacOS Extended Journaled used for Recovery)
- Core Storage
- APFS

These partition either can not be mount by Ubuntu are can be mounted as Read Only. So there is no danger of Ubuntu overwriting a macOS volume.

> Note: Most Linux (including Ubuntu) can write to non-encrypted Apple_HFS partitions if journaling is turned off. A macOS installation will always have journalling enabled by default.